# Cannot Compile GtkD project in Visual D

Tags: visual-studio, gtk, d

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, Visual D Version 0.3.37, Gtk+3.8, the latest GtkD and dmd-2.065.0, on Windows 7. I followed [these instructions](https://sites.google.com/site/gtkdtutorial/#chapter1_2) to build GtkD, and set up my compiler to compile it. In Visual Studio, I told VisualD to use the compiler switch that the instructions used to compile a project using GtkD. I tried to compile the "Hello World" program given in the instructions using the "Compile and Run" command of Visual D. After a long compilation I got the following error:

```
Compiling main.d...

OPTLINK (R) for Win32  Release 8.00.15
Copyright (C) Digital Mars 1989-2013  All rights reserved.
http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/optlink.html
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\lib\gtkd.lib(Action)  Offset 03B19H Record Type 0091 
Error 1: Previous Definition Different : _D3atk9ObjectAtk9ObjectAtk6__initZ
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\lib\gtkd.lib(Action)  Offset 03B42H Record Type 0091 
Error 1: Previous Definition Different : _D3atk9ObjectAtk9ObjectAtk7__ClassZ
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\lib\gtkd.lib(Action)  Offset 03B6AH Record Type 0091 
Error 1: Previous Definition Different : _D3atk9ObjectAtk9ObjectAtk6__vtblZ
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\..\lib\gtkd.lib(Action)  Offset FFE57H Record Type 0091 
Error 1: Previous Definition Different : _D3atk9ObjectAtk12__ModuleInfoZ 

//bunch more similar lines follow...

--- errorlevel 14816
Building Debug\main.exe failed!
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong; I followed the instructions exactly, and I know my compiler works. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you use a precompiled version? Also you can compile 64bit now btw.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error occurs because Visual Studio is compiling GtkD again, instead of simply using the `.d` files for reference and using the `.lib` file for the compiled implementation. You may need to either exclude GtkD files from compilation, or remove the `.lib` file from the project to let Visual Studio compile GtkD together with your application.